# how ro interact with a program's ui using another program to preform a brute force attack?

Tags: c++, winapi, brute-force

first of all this isn't for illegal purposes. rather for educational resons.

I made a program that basically ask for a username and a password and store them, and i can insert them later in a text box ui to "login". (Im using windows)

now i have a second program that is suppose to perform a brute force attack by trying a bunch of combinations of letters and numbers untill it cracks the password...
now my question is: is it possible (on windows) to interact with the ui of a program using another program ? and how ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it possible (on windows) to interact with the ui of a program using another program ? and how ?

Yes, this is possible. The technology to use is called [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). It will work with any application that uses a UI implemented using standard windowing systems (classic Win32, Windows Forms, WPF, WinUI).

It may not work for custom UI frameworks. If UI Automation doesn't work, nothing else will, unless there is a custom automation interface.

Comment: interesting thank you, do you think it would still be possible even if win32 api doesn't support it ?

Comment: @VoId All standard Win32 UI controls support UI Automation. Custom-made UI controls may or may not, depending on if and how they participate with the UI Automation APIs.